Why react query state is null after ssr prefetch?
issue: When I try to get users from db, react query returns null;

Framework: Nextjs 14, all packages are up to date
No errors during build
Completely good works in dev mode, but does not work in production mode(standalone)
I call getAllUsers inside useEffect(as you can see) and it returns users
tried to call jsonplaceholder and return users and it works
Other server actions, like for auth, email sending works well.
I run it with docker and also tried to run manually from .next/stadalone/server.js

action.ts:
    'use server';
    import { TUser } from '@/lib/types/users';
    import { db } from '@/lib/db';

    export const getAllUsers = async (): Promise<
      TUser[] | null | { message: string }
    > => {
    try {
        const users = await db.user.findMany();
        // const userData = [{ name: 'John Doe', email: 'asds' }];
        // console.log(users);

        if (!users) return { message: 'No users found' };

        return users;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('error', error);

        return null;
    }
    };

users/page.ts:
import React from 'react';
import UsersList from '@/components/users-list';
import {
    dehydrate,
    HydrationBoundary,
    QueryClient,
} from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { getAllUsers } from '@/actions/users';

const UsersPage = async () => {
    const queryClient = new QueryClient();
    await queryClient.prefetchQuery({
        queryKey: ['users'],
        queryFn: getAllUsers,
        staleTime: 100 * 60,
    });

    return (
        <HydrationBoundary state={dehydrate(queryClient)}>
            <UsersList />
        </HydrationBoundary>
    );
};

export default UsersPage;

users-list.ts:
const UsersList = () => {
    const { data: users } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ['users'],
        queryFn: getAllUsers,
        staleTime: 1000 * 60,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('users client', users);

        getAllUsers().then((data) => {
            console.log('data', data);
        });
    }, [users]);

    // return <DataTable columns={columns} data={users} isLoading={isPending} />;

    return (
        <div>
            <div>some data</div>
            <div>{JSON.stringify(users)}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default UsersList;


code looks okay, this should work. Do you have a minimal reproduction?
